# Modify rpm using rpmrebuild

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, rpmbuild

I have a rpm created for dev environment and CONTAINS a configuration file that points to dev. Now I have to create the rpm for another environment for which I need to **replace just one file in the SOURCES folder and update the reference in .spec and rebuild it**. Issue is that I don't have the .spec file that I used to create the rpm for dev.

So upon searching, came across rpmrebuild and I was able to see the .spec file in the editor. 
When I give rpmrebuild command, the spec file opens in the editor.

Here's the small snippet from the file

```
/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES
%files
%attr(0755, root, root) "/opt/**{replace/with/newfile/path**}"
```

But updating that that gives me - File not found: /root/.tmp/rpmrebuild.2345/work/root/opt/{path/to/newfile}

I don't know if I have to use rpmrebuild command with any --params in order to replace the file in the SOURCES and its reference in the .spec.  There are no other changes to be made.

Please guide.

Note: I am a unix novice

Answer (score 0):

I presume you do not have the src.rpm for this package. If you do, then it's very easy, simply install that with `rpm -ihv /path/to/src/rpm` as you would do with any RPM file. The contents, unless specified otherwise, will be extracted to ~/rpmbuild. The spec will be under ~/rpmbuild/SPECS, the sources under ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES, etc.

If you do not have the src.rpm but only the RPM itself, install the `rpmrebuild` package from the EPEL repos and then:

```sh
$ rpmrebuild -e -p /path/to/package
```

It will open the spec in your default editor. Edit it and save the spec wherever you want.
Then, assuming you have all the needed source files (declared in the spec using the `SourceN` directives), you can call:

```sh
$ rpmbuild -bb /path/to/spec
```

To rebuild the RPM from the edited spec.

Comment: I didn't have the source rpm. The .spec that gets opened in the editor doesn't look like the one I actually created. So for me, I had to just replace a file for which I had to do two things. 1 - Replace the file in sources folder & 2 - replace the file name reference in the spec file. So in the question, you could notice me replacing the old file name with new in /opt and I had already put the new file in SOURCES folder. And then, if I save this spec file - it will throw the error as provided in the question. Am I not editing the right place? There was no other reference to file anywhere else